# Difference between XSL and CSS

Tags: css, xslt

Maybe this is a stupid question, but what is the difference between XSL and CSS? They are both styling sheets. When would you want to use one over the other. I looked around and saw that CSS is generally used before XSL when possible... but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about XSLT rather than "XSL" (the latter term should be avoided because it is used in different ways by different people):

CSS provides a great deal of capability for rendering content. This capability is increasing all the time.

XSLT focuses on transforming content.

For example, you can write a report that groups, sorts, and summarizes data in XSLT, but you can't do so in CSS. Until recently CSS couldn't alter the content in any way, for example by rendering `<cite>3</cite>` as `[3]`.

You should use XSLT and CSS together. Use CSS for the pure rendering parts of the job, and XSLT for the transformation parts.

With the availability of Saxon-CE in the browser, you can also start to use XSLT for handling user interaction, such as responding to clicks by showing or hiding data: the kind of things you would otherwise have to do in Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

*XSL* is used to refer to a family of languages used to transform and render XML documents.

*CSS* is a style sheet language used for describing the presentation semantics (the look and formatting) of a document written in a markup language.

Hence XSL and CSS are not the same and not interchangeable. While XSL languages are used to impact the structure of XML documents (i.e. the arrangement of the tags) CSS is used to impact the *visual* formatting of those tags.

Edit: There are no stupid questions, just badly researched ones ;)